# Why the apt-get -f upgrade returns warning and errors?

Tags: debian, apt-get

I am trying to execute `apt-get -f upgrade` (because `apt-get upgrade` doesn't work)

But after that it prints very long list (as I see - for each package entry in `/var/lib/dpkg/status`) of warnings:

```
warning in file /var/lib/dpkg/status near line xx package xxxx: missing maintainer
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: that in line xx in the file /var/lib/dpkg/status the entry for the maintainer is missing. the maintainer is the guy who is responsible for a debian package. so goahed and look at line xx and post it here if you need help.

Comment: only because of the maintainers names are missing it can't install the packages and stream so many warnings and at the end an error (Sub-process dpkg returned an error code 2)?

Comment: this seems clearly to be a bug. you should report this to the debian project.